# Change String data from json to NSArray in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I've try to search around and can't find anything to solve the problem.
Here is the json reply like this and i want to change to [**NSDictionary**]:

```
let reply = "[{"qty":"3","price":"75000"},{"qty":"4","price":"75000"},    
{"qty":"1","price":"60000"},{"qty":"2","price":"60000"},{"qty":"6","price":"80000"}]"

let array = [{"qty":"3","price":"75000"},{"qty":"4","price":"75000"},
{"qty":"1","price":"60000"},{"qty":"2","price":"60000"},{"qty":"6","price":"80000"}]
```

Can someone please help me with examples. Thank you!

Comment: Use this library: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Do not – **never do** – use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift in conjunction with `JSON`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your statement:

```
i want to change to [NSDictionary]
```

I assume it as:

```
Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>  // using Swift v3
```

Although there is a more handy solution is to use SwiftyJSON library, but a non-third party solution could be:

```
let reply = "[{\"qty\":\"3\",\"price\":\"75000\"},{\"qty\":\"4\",\"price\":\"75000\"},{\"qty\":\"1\",\"price\":\"60000\"},{\"qty\":\"2\",\"price\":\"60000\"},{\"qty\":\"6\",\"price\":\"80000\"}]"

do {
       let data  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: reply.data(using: .utf8)!, options: .allowFragments) as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>

        let firstElement: Dictionary<String, Any> = data!.first!
        print("First dictionary element: \(firstElement)")
        print("Quantity from first dictionary element: \(firstElement["qty"] as! String)")
 }
 catch{
        print ("Handle error")
 }
```

Output:

```
First dictionary element: ["qty": 3, "price": 75000]
Quantity from first dictionary element: 3
```

**NOTE:**

I didn't handle the nil checks and also i converted string back to data to get json object, if you already have data no need to call `reply.data(using: .utf8)!` instead pass your data.

As per the above comment:

You can also equate:

```
Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = [[String: Any]]
Dictionary<String, Any>        =  [String: Any]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
 let jsonText = "[{\"qty\":\"3\",\"price\":\"75000\"},{\"qty\":\"4\",\"price\":\"75000\"},{\"qty\":\"1\",\"price\":\"60000\"},{\"qty\":\"2\",\"price\":\"60000\"},{\"qty\":\"6\",\"price\":\"80000\"}]"
        var myData:NSArray?

        if let data = jsonText.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {

            do {
                myData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSArray

                if let resultdata = myData
                {
                    print(resultdata)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

reply is already an array of Dictionary.  What are you actually asking?  If you need to convert a string representation of a json reply into a manageable structure, then as @Imad suggests, you should use one of the many JSON libraries that are available, and SwiftyJSON is one of the best.

Once you get your reply, all you need is something like this

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
```

Also, if you are including code, make sure it is real code - what you have shown will generate errors, but this will not.

```
let reply = [["qty":"3","price":"75000"],
             ["qty":"4","price":"75000"],
             ["qty":"1","price":"60000"],
             ["qty":"2","price":"60000"],
             ["qty":"6","price":"80000"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json_Parameters = NSArray() 

let reply = "[{\"qty\":\"3\",\"price\":\"75000\"},{\"qty\":\"4\",\"price\":\"75000\"},{\"qty\":\"1\",\"price\":\"60000\"},{\"qty\":\"2\",\"price\":\"60000\"},{\"qty\":\"6\",\"price\":\"80000\"}]"
```

Convert the  Json string to json data  and use the below code to type caste as an Array ()

```
if let data = reply.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
do {
    let datwa = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSArray
    json_Parameters = datwa
}
```

}

Comment: `NSArray` when dealing with JSON in Swift seems to be pretty easy but it's very very bad. You throw away the type information which is essential for the compiler to create efficient code. You are strongly discouraged from using Foundation collection types in Swift anyway.

Comment: @Vadian I have done only what "SawSoeMoeNyunt" asked.

Comment: @BraneDullet And sometimes only doing what OP wants is not the best answer. :)